# get_the_category return empty inside loop

Tags: categories, multisite, get-posts

I'm creating a custom template for my website and I'm currently using this code in order to loop to my multisite worpress and get the latest posts:

```
global $post;
global $wp_query;

$subsites = get_sites();
foreach( $subsites as $subsite ) {
    $subsite_id = get_object_vars($subsite)["blog_id"];
    $subsite_name = get_blog_details($subsite_id)->blogname;
    switch_to_blog($subsite_id);
    $blog_posts = get_posts(); 
    restore_current_blog();
    foreach( $blog_posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        get_template_part( 'theme-partials/post-templates/loop-content/masonry' );
    }
}
```

Inside the template_part the theme is trying to get the category for the post but return an empty array.

```
if ( pixelgrade_option( 'blog_show_categories' ) ) {
        $categories = get_the_category();
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $categories ) && ! empty( $categories ) ) { ?>
```

How could I get the category information inside the loop? 
What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Note that by calling `get_posts` without specifying `'suppress_filters' => false` WP can't use any caching or object caches, slowing things down considerably. It would be easier to just use a normal `WP_Query` loop instead. You should also check that `switch_to_blog` actually worked, but this code doesn't check if it returned true or false

Comment: I read in the doc that `get_posts` function internally call `WP_Query`. In addition the function `switch_to_blog` always return true, is it correct?
How can I change the get_posts into a WP_Query? Could you give me an example?

Comment: It does, but that doesn't mean it has identical behaviour. As for how to change them, that's a good question to ask, but a quick look at how to use `WP_Query` should make it obvious from the official docs. But comments aren't for answering questions or asking new ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```php
    switch_to_blog($subsite_id);
    $blog_posts = get_posts(); 
    restore_current_blog();
    foreach( $blog_posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        get_template_part( 'theme-partials/post-templates/loop-content/masonry' );
    }
```

Your code fetches a number of posts, but then you switch back to the original blog! So now post number 5 means something completely different than it did before.

You need to stay in that other blogs context for as long as you're working with that blogs data, or all the references will be incorrect. Once you `restore` the original blog you can't use that data.

Additionally, switching to another blog just changes the data that comes back, it won't load in plugins and code. This means only the filters, taxonomies, post types of the original blog are loaded.